# Fixed point power function for fractional values

Tags: perfect-powers

I am using below Matlab code to calculate power function i.e. without using built-in function.
My requirement is - What improvement/ suggestion make the below function support fractional base and exponential values to calculate power?
Thank you

```
b = [-32:32]; % example input values
e = [-3:3];   % example input values but doesn't support fraction's
    power_function(b,e)
        p = 1;
        if e < 0
            e = abs(e);
            multiplier = 1/b;
        else
            multiplier = b;
        end
        
        for k = 1:e
            p(:) = p * multiplier;
        end
```

Comment: Welcome to MSE. That question is off-topic here.

Comment: OK, where shall I ask ?

Comment: While I agree with @JoséCarlosSantos here are some remarks that you might find helpful: 1. fractional base is no problem with your current implementation. 2. If you want to support fractional exponents, you have to be able to get the $n$-th root for any given number $b.$ Either you use built-in functions or you  have to implement your own algorithm to get a numerical approximation for that. 3. Your approach is inefficient, because it loops $e$ times. You might want to take a look at [exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring)